# SQL MAX & MIN on same column around given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure like the following:

```
+------+------+-------------+
|Person| Code | DateOccur   |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1545 | A    |   1/1/2014  |
| 2324 | K    |   3/4/2014  |
| 2324 | j    |   3/8/2014  |
| 1545 | B    |   3/6/2014  |
| 5663 | J    |   3/2/2014  |
+------+------+-------------+
```

The Primary key could be seen as (`Person`, `DateOccur`), that is, there would never be two values with the same date for the same employee.

I want to form a query, given a particular date `SomeDate`, where I return the `MAX(DateOccur)` LESS than `SomeDate` as well as the `MIN(DateOccur)` GREATER than `SomeDate`, as well as the two associated codes.

An example with the table provided would be (w/ `SomeDate` = 3/3/2014):

```
+--------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| Person | CodeBefore | MaxDateBefore | CodeAfter | MinDateAfter |
+--------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
|   1545 | A          | 1/1/2014      | B         | 3/6/2014     | 
|   2324 | K          | 3/4/2014      | j         | 3/8/2014     | 
|   5663 | j          | 3/2/2014      | null      | null         |           
+--------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

What would be the simplest method of accomplishing this? I read a number of MAX/MIN StackOverflow questions, but I specifically need values around a specific date. I ideally just don't want to end up with something hacked together when I know there has to be a smooth way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Do this with conditional aggregation and then joining in the results.  Here is the code to get the dates:

```
select person, max(case when DateOccur < @TheDate then DateOccur end) as DateBefore,
       min(case when DateOccur > @TheDate then DateAfter end) as DateAfter
from table t
group by person;
```

And to get the rest:

```
select x.person, x.DateBefore, tbefore.code, x.DateAfter, tafter.code
from (select person, max(case when DateOccur < @TheDate then DateOccur end) as DateBefore,
             min(case when DateOccur > @TheDate then DateOccur end) as DateAfter
      from table t
      group by person
     ) x left outer join
     table tbefore
     on x.person = tbefore.person and x.DateBefore = tbefore.DateOccur left outer join
     table tafter
     on x.person = tafter.person and x.DateAfter = tafter.DateOccur;
```

Comment: In the code `min(case when DateOccur > @TheDate then DateAfter end)`, the `DateAfter`should be replaced by `DateOccur`

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to avoid using min/max -based subqueries?  Perhaps you can conceive of a solution around the ROW_NUMBER() OVER ranking function?  What do you want to happen if you have 2 rows in the first table with the same DateOccur value?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: This answer is more like a comment, not a final answer.

Comment: Well, for this table specifically, there cannot be two rows with the same DateOccur for the same employee. I should have mentioned that. Sorry!

Comment: Then a ROW_NUMBER() OVER solution would work for you without too much trouble.  Sorry Joe I don't like just writing code for people.  I am happy to help, just not trying to do their job for them.